# 3 Column Field Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

3 Column Field Bootstrap

I have this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gygs7pu9/) , weird is in jsFiddle its look okay ! all in 1 row, but when I run with my bootstrap code at my site, the textfield took the left over width, pushing whatever after it to the next line, regardless if its just a "%" (1 letter) or a string of words.

```
<div class="field">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="ticket_rebate">Ticket Rebate</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_rebate" placeholder="">% (e.g. 0 % to 12 %)
</div></div>
```

and my style code..

```
.field, .actions {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .field label {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
  }
.field input:not([type="radio"]) {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
```

Problem is it appear that

```
Ticket Rebate [   Text Field    ]
   % (e.g. 0 % to 12 %)
```

The % (e.g. 0 % to 12 %) unable to be same row as the Ticket Rebate & the Text Field.
It seems the Text Field took all the leftover width, I not sure how to make it so that it appear, all in 1 row, the text field is 0 to 3 character, it does not need to be very big in width.

```
Ticket Rebate [   Text Field    ] % (e.g. 0 % to 12 %)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.form-control` is diplayed `block` which is declared in bootstrap CSS.

You need to set the input's `display` to `inline-block`

```
#ticket_rebate{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/gygs7pu9/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## [DEMO with bootstrap 3](http://jsfiddle.net/gygs7pu9/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="form-group row text-center"><!--Using text-center on parent is like margin:0 auto-->
        <label class=col-lg-4 for="ticket_rebate">Ticket Rebate</label>
        <input class=col-lg-6 type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_rebate" placeholder=""/>
        <span  class=col-lg-2>% (e.g. 0 % to 12 %)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.field, .actions {
    /*extra css goes here*/
  }
  .field label {
    /*extra css goes here*/
  }
.field input:not([type="radio"]) {
   /*extra css goes here*/
  }
```

Now you can make it reponsive by add classes for `col-xs` , `col-md` , `col-lg`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding form-inline class?

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="field">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ticket_rebate">Ticket Rebate</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ticket_rebate" placeholder="">% (e.g. 0 % to 12 %)
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```